# How to use same python interpreter on terminal and on PyCharm?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, pycharm

I want to run some scripts using PyCharm and not by terminal `python turtlebotrun.py`.

When I run it **from terminal it is working** but when I run it on PyCharm it says

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ros/Desktop/project/turtlebotrun.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ros/Desktop/project/turtlebotrun.py", line 2, in <module>
    from turtlebot import Turtlebot
ImportError: No module named turtlebot

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I use same interpreter path on PyCharm settings as `sys.path` shows on terminal. Versions are in both 2.7.

How can I fix this? Am I using the same interpreter? How can I check it?

**Update 1:**
There are multiple paths. I added all those to pycharm but nothing. I used `sys.path` on same file and the first I executed it via terminal and the second with Pycharm

Terminal:

```
    ros@xxxxx:~/Desktop/project$ python turtlebotrun.py
    ['/home/ros/Desktop/project',
     '/home/ros/ros_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
     '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
     '/home/ros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', 
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

Pycharm:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ros/Desktop/project/turtlebotrun.py
['/home/ros/Desktop/project',
 '/home/ros/Desktop/project/turtlebotrun.py', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
 '/home/ros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you see at results these directories are **missing** even if are added to paths on pycharm settings

`/home/ros/ros_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages,
 /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

So the **question** is: why these directories are not used?
Maybe this is why cant run scripts form PyCharm

Comment: did you do a `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`? Because that one is needed for tk and turtle.

Comment: It is python 2.7 and it is running correct if I use `python turtlebotrun.py`  from terminal. Why should I install python3-tk?

Comment: Re your update 1: file turtlebotrun.py is in multiple directories? Does `python turtlebotrun.py` work regardless of the directory you issue the command in? What's your $PYTHONPATH? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135035/python-library-path may help.

Comment: I updated the question